# merging mutidimensional arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:
getting array need to convert array as same key value as 0

```
        foreach($array as $key=>$id){               

            $consumer_data[]=$this->App_model->get_session($id);
        }

        print_r($consumer_data);

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ConsumerID] => 1
                [name] => asdfd
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ConsumerID] => 5
                [name] => test
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ConsumerID] => 3
                [name] => test1
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ConsumerID] => 4
                [name] => test4
            )

    )
```

i want to implement array like this in same key value as 0

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ConsumerID] => 1
                [name] => asdfd
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ConsumerID] => 5
                [name] => test
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ConsumerID] => 3
                [name] => test1
            )
       [3] => Array
            (
                [ConsumerID] => 4
                [name] => test4
            )


    )
```

I am using PHP. Can anyone point me to a good starting point as to how I should go about doing this?

Comment: How do you build these array? Small solution, Otherwise $array1[0][] = $array2[1][0];

Comment: $array contain with key 0 and 1 but i need to convert into 0 as key value only .

Comment: Could you show us some code how you come up with the current output? Otherwise we can only show pseudo-code solution without really helping you.

Comment: So from a 3 dimensional array to a 3 dimensional array ? your title sucks. What you actually want to do is just use array_merge()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**array_merge()**](https://www.php.net/array_merge):

```
$new_array[0] = array_merge($array[0], $array[1]);
```

Where `$array` is the first array.

[**SEE DEMO**](http://codepad.org/bp3WRjEm)

**OR** for a more dynamic approach:

```
$new_array = array(0 => array());
foreach($array as $a) {
    $new_array[0] = array_merge($new_array[0], $a);
}
```

[**SEE DEMO 2**](http://codepad.org/5SfR2tAg)

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest solution is to do it with:

```
$input = array(
    array(
        array('ConsumerID' => 1, 'name' => 'asdfd'),
        array('ConsumerID' => 5, 'name' => 'test'),
        array('ConsumerID' => 4, 'name' => 'test1'),
    ),
    array(
        array('ConsumerID' => 4, 'name' => 'test4'),
    ),
);
$output = array(
    array()
);

foreach ($input as $data) {
    $output[0] = array_merge($output[0], $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this->

```
 $newArray = array();
  foreach($values as $key=>$val){
      $newArray [0][$key]=$val;

  }
  print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<?php
$arr[0] = array(0 => array("ConsumerID" => 1, "name" => "Ni"), 1 => array("ConsumerID" => 2, "name" => "Ab")); 
$arr[1] = array(1 => array("ConsumerID" =>5, "name" => "GE"), 1 => array("ConsumerID" => 6, "name" => "DB"));  

$new = array();

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {


        foreach($value as $innerkey => $innervalue) {

                $new[0][] = $innervalue;

        }
}


print_r($new);
?>
```